# How to enable visual editor when editing comments on the dashboard?

Tags: filters, comments, hooks, visual-editor, wp-editor

For editing a comment in admin pages the editor is only html, can we modify the edit comment page with a filter to include visual editor too?

Comment: I actually started another question while messing around with this and trying to do a similar task to what you want. The closest answer that I've gotten is there, except you'd replace the $settings['quicktags'] = false; to $settings['tinymce'] = true; instead to get the visual editor on the Edit Comments admin page: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168391/am-i-using-the-right-hook-for-removing-quicktags-on-the-admin-tinymce#answer-168407 I didn't want to put it as an answer and take credit for code that doublesharp wrote. I just edited that one line for your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using WordPress 4.0+ you can do this using the `wp_editor_settings` and the `global $pagenow` to determine if you are on the comments page.

```
add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'remove_editor_quicktags', 10, 2 );
function remove_editor_quicktags( $settings, $id ){
    global $pagenow; 
    if ( $id == 'content' && $pagenow === 'comment.php' ){
        $settings['quicktags'] = false;
        $settings['tinymce'] = true;
    }
    return $settings;
}
```

Comment: Might want to change 'edit-comments.php' to 'comment.php'. That's what worked for me on the Edit Comment admin page.

Comment: good call, i lazily grabbed the comment listing page. didn't actually run the above code, just free formed it :)