# Am I using the right hook for removing quicktags on the admin TinyMCE?

Tags: filters, hooks, tinymce, comment-form

This is more of an excercise than something for a client.

Anyway, **I'm trying to disable the quicktags when you're on the dashboard** and you click on **Comments > Edit Comment**. On that screen, there's a TinyMCE with quicktags and the textarea has an id of "content".

I know in the WordPress core, this can be changed on line 67 of wp-admin/edit-form-comment.php by changing this:

```
wp_editor( $comment->comment_content, 'content', array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce' => false, 'quicktags' => $quicktags_settings ) );
```

To this (quicktags set to false):

```
wp_editor( $comment->comment_content, 'content', array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce' => false, 'quicktags' => false ) );
```

But I obviously don't want to edit core and want to do this via filter/hook. This is what I tried.

```
function disable_tinymce_quicktags_comments ( $args ) {
  ob_start();
  $comment = get_comment_to_edit( $comment_id );
  wp_editor( $comment->comment_content, 'content', array( 'quicktags' => false ) );
  $args = ob_get_contents(); 
  ob_end_clean();
  return $args;
}

add_filter( 'admin_init', 'disable_tinymce_quicktags_comments' );
```

A `var_dump` of $args is revealing nothing after the return, and this is what the text editor looks like on the Edit Comment screen with this function happening:

[image]

Am I just trying to achieve the impossible or am I just using the wrong hook? I'm still learning about hooks and PHP. Any suggestions? Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking out the code, the best way to do this would be to use the `wp_editor_settings` filter in [`/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L76). When you call `wp_editor()` it internally makes a call to `_WP_Editors::editor($content, $editor_id, $settings);`. This function first passes the `$settings` array through `parse_settings()` which uses that filter.

```
add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'remove_editor_quicktags', 10, 2 );
function remove_editor_quicktags( $settings, $id ){
    // $id will be 'content' in your example
    // use it in an if or make it gone for everything...

    // use $pagenow to determine if you are on the edit comments page.
    global $pagenow; 
    if ( $pagenow === 'comment.php' ){
        $settings['quicktags'] = false;
    }
    return $settings;
}
```

*Note - I just realized this filter is new as of WordPress 4.0, so you will need it or newer to take advantage. This also affects all instances of TinyMCE on the admin.*

Comment: Hmm it looks like the wp_editor_settings hook works but it affects all instances of the TinyMCE on the admin, not just the Edit Comment admin page. So it removes the "text" tab on the post/page editors. Is there any way to target specific admin pages to run this? Looks like there isn't a conditional that would help as is_admin just generally checks if you're on the dash, correct?

Comment: I also credited this answer to another person's question with just one line changed, hope you don't mind. Added it as a comment and it's somewhat relevant to my question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168099/how-to-enable-visual-editor-when-editing-comments-on-the-dashboard

Comment: Ah I missed the comment for the $id - unfortunately this doesn't work in this case because the editor on Edit Comment and the editor on a post/page (text mode) both use the same id which is "content". So I can't target a specific editor using this method.

Comment: If it is on the admin side you can use the global `$pagenow` to control it too.

Comment: Updated the answer to show this.

Comment: And I will post an answer to the other question, thanks!

Comment: it works except  $pagenow === 'edit-comments.php' didn't work on the Edit Comment page, but  $pagenow === 'comment.php' did. If you add that in your answer, I'll mark as correct so we can shorten our comment spam. :-) Thanks.