# Remove quicktag buttons but not Visual / Text editor and tabs

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor, quicktag

I wish to remove the quick-tag buttons in the text (html) editor in TinyMCE but not the html editor itself nor the tabs for choosing between the editors.

When I use

```
   $settings = array('quicktags' => false);
   wp_editor($input, 'editor_name', $settings);
```

Wordpress removes the entire text editor and the Visual / Text tabs for choosing between the editors (as stated in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor)). I have tried

```
   $settings = array('quicktags' => array());
```

But all buttons remain. Looking through the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js#L0) I cannot see a new native remove button code, just add. For backwards compatibility there is listed a `edRemoveTag = function(){},` but I cannot find the actual function itself.

I have only found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168391/am-i-using-the-right-hook-for-removing-quicktags-on-the-admin-tinymce) related thread for quicktags in WP4.0 but it does not seem to cover this issue.

Comment: The plugin AddQuicktag give you this possibility with help a settings page, see https://github.com/bueltge/AddQuicktag

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter to early on my mobile. You find also the example, the solution for doing this inside this class of  the plugin f custom source, see https://github.com/bueltge/AddQuicktag/blob/master/inc/class-remove-quicktags.php

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to eliminate the need for plugins

Comment: Yes, I have understand this. But in the class of my second comment can you find the hooks and functions to remove the quicktags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, setting quicktags to false removes the "visual" and "text" tabs. So, to leave the tabs you need to set quicktags to true and remove the buttons:

```
$settings = array(
    'quicktags' => array(
                       'buttons' => ','
                    )
);
wp_editor($input, 'editor_name', $settings);
```

To have this in all quicktags instances you can use `quicktags_settings` filter:

```
add_filter('quicktags_settings', 'cyb_quicktags_settings');
function cyb_quicktags_settings( $qtInit  ) {
    //Set to emtpy string, empty array or false won't work. It must be set to ","
    $qtInit['buttons'] = ',';
    return $qtInit;
}
```

If you are using a plugin that add custom quicktags, you may to set a high priority argument to the filter (later execution):

```
add_filter('quicktags_settings', 'cyb_quicktags_settings', 100);
```

Comment: Well done spotting that out (+1), I was just going to start looking through the Javascript code. I'm just curious, where did you find the condition responsible for this, that the comma escapes through the "eye of the needle" ?

Comment: [See code reference for `quicktags_settings` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/quicktags_settings/).

Comment: I already checked that one out, but couldn't see the comma solution from that. So that's why I started to look at the javascript.

Comment: Ah, I tried to unset `$qInit['buttons']`, set it to false and set it to empty string with no sucess. Then I saw line 302 of wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php; note the `explode(',', $qtInit['buttons'])` in that line. I realised that `$qInit['buttons']` is a string of comma separated buttons names.

Comment: aha, thanks for sharing - I tried various cases, but not the one in your answer ;-)

Comment: ps: `$settings['quicktags'] = array( 'buttons' => ',' );` should then also work in the `wp_editor_settings` filter callback.

Comment: Yes, it should work. I've tested in the settings argument of `wp_editor()` and also work. See edited answer.

Comment: Ah, that comma thing is a bug in "wp-includes/js/quicktags.js", line 263 `if ( settings.buttons ) {` should be `if ( typeof settings.buttons === 'string' ) {`, otherwise a blank `qtInit` buttons setting gets ignored.

Comment: I don't agree with you @bonger, it is not a bug in the javascript code, instead it is the way it is handle in the PHP script.

Comment: @cybmeta Well the php isn't the greatest but setting `$qtInit['buttons']` to `''` in the filter is more natural and produces a qtInit setting in the HTML with buttons set to `""` which should be respected by the javascript I would have thought. Anyway I think I'll raise a ticket about it...

Comment: Submit the ticket if you want, it would be great if setting `$qtInit['buttons']` to empty string or empty array is respected, but as I said, it has nothing to do with javascript. In PHP `$qtInit['buttons']` is first a string, then is converted to array; if the original string is empty, it is ignored and the default buttons array is used. Finally, **it is that array which is passed to javascript**. If, as you said, javascript tries to check the settings buttons variable as string it will break. The issue is in PHP side.

Comment: I think you're misreading the code, it's `self::$qt_settings[$editor_id]` that gets passed to the javascript (via `_parse_init()`), not `self::$qt_buttons` which is just used internally.

Comment: This is my last comment, I think this not the place to discuss this. A quick test: change line 302 of "wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php" to `self::$qt_buttons = array();` and you will see the effect. The problem is in that line of PHP code (maybe also in other PHP places), not in javascript.

Comment: Well you're wrong but it doesn't matter and we can all follow the exciting story on https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30942.