# WP_Editor - Remove TinyMCE Toolbars

Tags: gallery, tinymce, wp-editor

I've created a TinyMCE Editor in a Metabox and I'm trying to remove the toolbars. According to [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) I should be able to pass it an array of options to override the default TinyMCE. Here's what I have:

```
wp_editor( $content, 'my_editor_id', array(
    'textarea_name'     => '_meta_editor',
    'tinymce'           => array(
        'toolbar1'      => '',
        'toolbar2'      => ''
    ),
    'drag_drop_upload'  => true
) );
```

I've also tried replacing the empty string to `false` but they still show the default parameters. The purpose is I only want to use the editor for Post Galleries and do not want to give the user access to any of the other TinyMCE Options.

If I just give the TinyMCE the following option: `'tinymce' => array()` it still puts options in the toolbar and it removes my gallery preview ( which I do not want ).

List of things I've tried:

- `'tinymce' => array()` - removes everything, gallery preview - need gallery preview
- `'tinymce' => array( 'toolbar1' => '' )` - nothing happens
- `'tinymce' => array( 'toolbar1' => array() )` - nothing happens
- `'tinymce' => array( 'toolbar1' => array( ',' ) )` - nothing happens
- `'tinymce' => array( 'toolbar1' => ',' )` - nothing happens
- `'tinymce' => array( 'toolbar1' => false )` - nothing happens

Did TinyMCE change it's index names or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try the comma string `'toolbar1' => array( ',' )` ? It might be related to the answer + discussion in comments [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174086/26350).

Comment: @birgire I've tried that and `','`

Comment: ps: yes I meant to write `'toolbar1' => ','` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this should remove the toolbars on the tinyMCE:

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
    $in['toolbar1'] = '';
    $in['toolbar2'] = '';
    $in['toolbar'] = false;
    return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```

References:
https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration

For the wp_editor, try applying these filter parameters onto your wp_editor() function.

Hope it helps.

** Edit

Also if that `['toolbar'] = false;` still prevents you from uploading galleries, you could just try this instead:

```
$in['toolbar1'] = 'undo,redo'; 
$in['toolbar2'] = '';
```

(Just add a couple of buttons like undo and redo to the top toolbar and remove the second). I've just tested this and it works with adding galleries.

Comment: While, what you're referring to is the Default tinyMCE, I'm using the [`wp_editor()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) function to generate a separate tinyMCE ( so your filter wouldn't apply ). I did apply your filter parameters onto my function and it worked :D ! Thanks for your suggestion, if you could edit your answer and apply it onto the `wp_editor()` instead I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Also if that ['toolbar'] = false; still prevents you from uploading galleries, you could just try this instead: 
 $in['toolbar1'] = 'undo,redo';
 $in['toolbar2'] = ''; (Just add a couple of buttons like undo and redo to the top toolbar and remove the second). I've just tested this and it works with adding galleries.